# How can I get the values like gender , age while using google sign in Api in my flutter app though I am new in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-android

I am Trying to get the gender of a signed in user but I am getting Error like "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6709): Receiver: null"

> //This is My google_signIn_api.dart file

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GoogleSignInApi {
  String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
  static final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: ['email', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]);

  static Future<GoogleSignInAccount> login() => _googleSignIn.signIn();

  static Future<String> getGender() async {
    final headers = await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
    final r = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=genders&key=******"),
        headers: {"Authorization": headers["Authorization"]});
    final response = jsonDecode(r.body);
    print(response);
    return response["genders"][0]["formattedValue"];
  }
}
```

This is the code where I am trying to print the value

```
Future signIn() async {
    final user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();
    String gender;
    if (user == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Sign in Failed')));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => RegistrationScreen(user.displayName),
          ));
      // print(user.)
      print(user);
      gender = await GoogleSignInApi.getGender();
      print(user.id);
      print(user.email);
      print("-------");
      print(gender);
      print("========");
      print(user.displayName);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does print(response); out put?

Comment: Remember if the user haven't added a gender ["genders"][0] will probably be null.

Comment: You should be following something like this https://flutteragency.com/use-google-api-in-flutter/

Comment: Yes it is giving "The method '[]' was called on null" so the user haven't added gender .

Answer (score -1):

this is not unique to flutter, this is universal when interacting with google oauth on any platform

you need to add additional scopes

currently you are only requesting scope for

```
scopes: ['email', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]);
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Comment: After Using the additional scope getting the same error , If you could please specify how to solve or is there any thing I am doing wrong .

Comment: did you read the link ?

Comment: Yes read the doc and I used this scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read".  did I miss something ?

Comment: Author has already added that scope in their code.  Nor is this an error with scopes.  A scope error would give you a missing consent error. For a full list of scopes for this method check [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) scroll to the bottom it shows the scopes you can use.

Comment: @ShadmanNehalKhan did you read the big red box in the top of the link, are you verified  as per the big red box in the link ?

Comment: Got it I am not verified but thanks for clearing this .

Comment: no problem, once verified you can add all your scopes on the one line of code i.e. scopes: ['email', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read"]);

Answer (score -1):

> ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. E/flutter ( 6709): Receiver: null"

Means that you are trying to requst data from a value that is currently null.

If the user has not added a gender then `response["genders"][0]` will be null so trying to request data from a null value by doing `response["genders"][0]["formattedValue"]`;

Will result in a NoSuchMethodError error.

## Clarification

Another answer was posted stating that your issue is with your scopes. I want to be user you understand that this is **not** the issue.

Each method in this case [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) lists in the documentation what scope are required to use it.  In this case one of these

[image]

You are using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` so you r error is not due to scopes. I know this becouse the error message you would have been getting would be

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.people.v1.PeopleService.GetPerson",
          "service": "people.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```